# php date strtotime +3 day gives me a date between 2 and 3 day from the start?

Tags: php, time

I need a conversion from a date and add +3 days. When I use the strtotime("last wed +3 day"); it gives me a date between 2 and 3 days. It doesn't work on my server and on the interent I've tested it with codepad: http://codepad.org/MhL77CVC and http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php. It gives me a time between 2 and 3 days from the last wedsday and it's 7:00:00pm EST. Where I live is +1 Utc. What I need is something at 00:00 and I thought it is possible? My client isn't very helpfully with his answers. He thinks everthing works in +1 UTC timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to convert string to time. Second parameter accepts time zone, use [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php).

```
$z = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
$d = new DateTime("last wed +3 day", $z);
echo $d->format("d.m.Y H:i");
echo $d->format("U"); # or echo $d->getTimestamp(); on PHP > 5.3.0
```

[DateTime::format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method accepts format like [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: Thanks, I need the timestampe I've tried get_timestamp(); See here: http://codepad.org/GWQyhL38. It doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know that PHP version does codepad.org use, but http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php requires > 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

if you need to transform timezones you can use `date_default_timezone_set()`

```
    $date = new DateTime("last wed +3 day", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome')); 

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome'); 
    echo date("Y-m-d h:iA", $date->format('U')); 
    echo "<br/>";
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
    echo date("Y-m-d h:iA", $date->format('U'));
```

You can also solve the problem by setting the rigt timezone at the beginning of script

Comment: Do you mean date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); and I can use strtotime in my script?

Comment: Hmm. I try but do you think +3 day from last weds gives me fri 24:00?

Comment: So PHP is calculating last wed +3 day to to fri 24:00?